Forwarding https traffic from openvpn to internal server which has internet access
I am trying to achieve the following behaviour
Client <--> openvpn at 1194 <--> internal server at port 8080 <--> internet
I used iptables prerouting route on nat with DPORT 80 and 443. I can able to see http request flowing through internal server but https server are not working as expected
When I check the ipaddress from my client , for http request it shows internal server correctly but for https it is still showing  openvpn ip only and even i switched off my internal server but still client is able to access to https
**Both openvpn(ubuntu) and internal serve(windows) hosted in aws ec2 and has public ip and inbound traffic opened **
